# $t is undefined inside of component filter

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have filter on my component

```
filters: {
formatStatus (value) {
  let status = {
    active: {
      text: this.$t('general.successful'),
      class: 'secondary--text'
    },
    processing: {
      text: this.$t('general.processing'),
      class: 'tertiary--text'
    },
    waiting: {
      text: this.$t('general.pending'),
      class: 'tertiary--text'
    }
  }
  return status[value]
}
}
```

but i got an error
TypeError: Cannot read property '$t' of undefined

but on methods,
$t is working fine.

Comment: Inside `filters:` this = undefined, not your vue instance. And "filter should be pure - no side effects, just data in and data out".. you can use methods or computed property instead.

Comment: I see, so it should be standalone.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rearraing your code like this. it will work

```
   filters: {
formatStatus (value,self) {
  let status = {
    active: {
      text: self.$t('general.successful'),
      class: 'secondary--text'
    },
    processing: {
      text: self.$t('general.processing'),
      class: 'tertiary--text'
    },
    waiting: {
      text: self.$t('general.pending'),
      class: 'tertiary--text'
    }
  }
  return status[value]
}
}
```

call filter like :

```
{{yourvalue | formatStatus(this)}}
```